# how to set the format for date time column in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning

> 11am – 4pm, 7:30pm – 11:30pm (Mon-Sun)------(this is opening and closing time of restaurant)
>   [i have this kind of format in my TIME column and this is not converting into datetime format...so how to prepare the data so that i can apply linear regression???]

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '11am – 4pm, 7:30pm – 11:30pm (Mon-Sun)')

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, datetime format requires the 24h format, or - 00:00:00
So instead of 7:30pm, it would be 19:30:00.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['11/8/2011', '04/23/2008', '10/2/2019'], 
                'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre'], 
                'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000]})

print(df)

df.info()
```